# Magento onestepcheckout clearing cart

Tags: magento, onestepcheckout

I've been using the OnestepCheckout extension for Magento with success for a long while.
But now I want to set up multiple store views. I set this up correctly, but when I add a store code to the urls, the checkout page empties my cart.

`domain.com -> domain.com/onestepcheckout` works fine.
But:
`domain.com/en -> domain.com/en/onestepcheckout` clears the cart

How is this possible? Has it something to do with the setup for cookie domains?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are loosing your session during redirection time so monitor your front-end session id and see if this changes. If it changes then you are loosing your cart.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
Session ID got reset on the Checkout page. Problem was a missing image and incorrect 404 config.